# How to get the Height of a popup Before loading - Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, popup, width

```
$("[data-toggle=popover]").popover({
    html: true,
    trigger: 'touchstart',
    animation: true,
    content: function () {
        return ShowPopup();
    }
});
```

ShowPopup() function returns popup Html.The popup size is dynamic according to image in the popup.

So I want the total height of the popup before loading as popup window.

Comment: The best approach would be to create hidden popup and then get it's height (not `display: none` but `visibility: hidden` and `position: absolute`)

Answer (score 0):

Use height() function of jquery

```
var height = $("#poppupidorselector").height()
```

Lets us know if it helps

**PS**:In your case you can put the html of poppup in hidden div and then get the height